# CentOS, unix find out length of a LONG or INT via Command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I used a command similar to "length(LONG)" at the UNIX to find out the length of a long (8 on 64 bit, 4 on 32 bit ). What was that command!

Comment: Possibly a locally installed script. I know of no similar standard command.

Comment: Note that the length of a long/int really has very little to do with your operating system/environment. It is a function of the compiler/interpreter you are using. It is entirely possible to have a 32-bit compiler with 32-bit ints on a 64-bit platform and vice versa. You could even find a 16-bit compiler in some cases, with 16-bit ints (although that might possibly be non-compliant with modern standards, depending on what programming language you are using; however, there is still occasional valid use for such things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the LONG_BIT configuration variables with getconf:

```
$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
```